# Pgadmin interface within a iframe

Tags: html, iframe, localhost, embed, pgadmin

How can I embed pgadmin inside iframe? I have a working instance in localhost when open a page but Id doesn't not work (connection refused) when I try to embed it inside a iframe (always in localhost).
Here the simple html that I use to test:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8082/pgadmin" target="_blank">Open in new tab</a>
```

There is an iframe below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution with support of pgadmin team. If anyone interested, the issue with solution is in their Redmine repository:
https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/6105

Comment: The link unavailable to read now - it require login. Can you copy the answer to stackoverflow?